# General question on subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if it possible for a sequence to have three different subsequences, one converging to 1, one to 2, and another to 3? I think it does but don't know what the sequence is.

Comment: How about $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\ldots$?

Comment: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...

Comment: Was this exact question not asked recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence defined by $$a_n=\begin{cases}1-\frac{1}{n} :\quad n\equiv0\pmod{3}\\2-\frac{1}{n}:\quad n\equiv1\pmod{3}\\3-\frac{1}{n}:\quad n\equiv2\pmod{3}\end{cases}$$suffices for $n>0$.

Comment: Is there a simpler sequence? I am not good with modular arithmetic.

Comment: $n\equiv0\pmod{3}$ just means $n=3k$ for some positive integer $k$. $n\equiv1\pmod{3}$ means $n=3k+1$ and similarly for $n\equiv2\pmod{3}$ we have $n=3k+2$. It cycles in the same way as $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\ldots$ but is less trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a sequence that converges to 1, one that converges to 2, and another that converges to 3, and interleave them.
(E.g. 1,2,3,1,2,3, $\cdots$ )

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=n+1-3\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}3\right\rfloor$$